# how to check whether email is sent

Tags: javascript, cordova, email

```
 cordova.plugins.email.open({
    subject: 'Credentials for Joe Lally',
    body: emailbody,
    isHtml: true
    //       attachments: cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + 
     localStorage.getItem("uuid") + ".txt"

},callback,scope);
function callback(result)
{
    alert(result);
}
function scope(result)
{
    alert(result)
}
```

}

i want to how can we check whether email has sent or not using cordova,I used in call back function but it every time returning okay.Can anybody help me in checking the status.

Answer (score 1):

You can't check it with this plugin. See the @PKnittel's [answer](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer/issues/100)

Comment: Yes. Android don´t serve any kind of Email-Intent wich allow to check that information.
So we decided to not implement this feature cause of cross-platform-consistency.

It was said like this?

Comment: Did my answer help you?